# Traversing an XSL DOM using C# and XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I'm trying to do some post-processing on an XSLT document before it's handed off for XML transformation. I thought the best option would be to load it up as an XmlDocument and then traverse through the to-be-updated nodes with SelectNodes like I usually do but I seem to be having trouble locating the nodes I need. Every query just comes back with 0 nodes found.

I suspect it has something to do with the Namespaces but can't figure out how.

Sample XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <a href="/">
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample C#:

```
XmlDocument style = new XmlDocument();
style.Load("sample.xslt");
foreach (XmlNode anchor in style.SelectNodes("//a"))
  ...
```

But it never finds the `<a>` tag - or any other tags I try.

I've tried changing the code to this:

```
XmlDocument style = new XmlDocument();
style.Load("sample.xslt");

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(style.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("xsl", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform");

foreach (XmlNode anchor in style.SelectNodes("//a", nsmgr))
  ...
```

This actually lets me select the nodes with the `xsl:` prefix (e.g. `.SelectNodes("/xsl:stylesheet")`) but none of the inner, HTML nodes.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to let the XPAth selector know you want the HTML element. Although the HTML elements are not prefixed, they do have a 'default namespace'.

In your XPath you'll have to reflect this.

Add "html" as prefix with "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" as namespace uri to the namespace manager.

Then prefix your XPath with html: for queries about the html elements.

Hope this helps,